# How to indicate "loading" state for an async action during first render using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Say I have a redux module that looks like this:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

// CONSTANTS
const LOAD = 'LOAD';
const LOAD_SUCCESS = 'LOAD_SUCCESS';

// REDUCER
const initialState = { loading: false, data: [] };

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD: return { ...state, loading: true };
    case LOAD_SUCCESS: return { ...state, loading: false, data: action.data };
    default: return state;
  }
}

// ACTION CREATORS
function requestLocations() {
  return { type: LOAD };
}

function receiveLocations(json) {
  return { type: LOAD_SUCCESS, data: json };
}

export function fetchLocations() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestLocations());

    return fetch('http://myurl')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveLocations(json)));
  };
}
```

I'm struggling with the `loading` state on the first render if I make the async call in componentWillMount.  Imagine my component looks like this (simplified for brevity):

```
export default class LocationContainer extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    fetchLocations(); // already bound and injected via connect.
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, data } = this.props; // injected via connect from reducer above.
    if (loading) {
      return <Spinner />;
    } else {
      return <LocationExplorer locations={ data } />;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I run into is that on the first render of `LocationContainer`, `loading` is false and `data` hasn't been fetched yet.  In `componentWillMount`, the `LOAD` action is fired and a props change of `loading` being set to true is queued up to happen on the subsequent render.  In the meantime, during my first render, `LocationExplorer` is rendered when I really wanted `Spinner` instead because `loading` is still false. I'm wondering how you deal with this without setting a `firstRender = true` state variable hack.

Comment: I have taken a closer look to your code and I have detected a weird thing. In your `componentWillMount` method you are calling `requestLocations`? Shouldn't it be `fetchLocations`?

Comment: Yeah, this was just a quick illustration I whipped up.  Updated the code to use the proper function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option could be extend your `loading` condition with your `data` initial state:

```
const initialState = { loading: false, data: [] };
```

When you are `loading` and your `data` is empty it means you are in this exact state of waiting for new data to come:

```
if (loading && data.length === 0) {
  return <Spinner />;
} else {
```

Also, I usually put my asynchronous calls in `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`.

Comment: Moving the call to `componentDidMount` means the action fires even later, creating a longer wait for the data.

Comment: @DavidWalsh Yep, you are right. I have been using AJAX in my [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) because the doc said that :). Not sure why `componentWillMount` is not the recommended place.

Comment: This is currently what I'm doing in regards to checking length or != null on the collection.  One thing I don't love about this, is what would happen if data happened to be empty after the server responded?  In this case, I wouldn't want the spinner -- perhaps a message to create a new thing.  Wish there was a simpler way of doing this, but sadly there doesn't appear to be anything better.

Comment: Should't it be loading || data.length === 0 rather than loading && data.length === 0?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the request in `componentWillMount`. Instead, do it before you mount the component. e.g.

```
store.dispatch(fetchLocations());
ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, mountpoint);
```

Comment: A legitimate suggestion, but this may be hard with route-based apps (where the component defines what data needs to be fetched at start)

Comment: if your on ES6+ you use a Decorator

Comment: Decorators are not part of any standard. I would discourage their use.

Comment: [official Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) actively discourages fetching data under `componentWillMount`. If you are going to suggest otherwise, then it would be helpful to explicitly state why and under what conditions to deviate from official recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Besides the accepted answer, one other solution we've been using to great success is adding a `complete` boolean flag to the reducer and we mark it true if a response has come back at some point. This makes things a bit more explicit in the event the response actually comes back with an empty array.  The `complete` flag lets me know that the response is from the server and not just my initial state.

```
if(loading && !complete) {
  return <Spinner />;
} else {
  return <Component data={data} />;
}
```

I figured I would add this just in case it's helpful to others.